# Certain PHP fields will not show up in email message from form

Tags: php, forms

I'm using a template, and the pre built fields in my form that came with the theme are sending to my email, however, I've added additional fields, but they are not getting posted. The phone, location, contacttime, and date labels all show, but the input data for these fields do not send with the form.

```
<?php
// Your Email
$recipient = "myemail@email.com"; // PLEASE SET YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS
$recaptcha_secret_key = 'yourAPIkey'; // PLEASE SET YOUR GOOGLE RECAPTCHA API KEY. If you are not using, please leave it blank.

if(!empty($recaptcha_secret_key) && array_key_exists('recaptcha',$_POST) ) {
    returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
        constructAjaxResponseArray(
            FALSE,
            'RECAPTCHA_FAILED_CHECK',
            array('error_message'=> 'RECAPTCHA_FAILED_CHECK')
        )
    );
}

// Recaptcha check up
// Requires curl. If your server does not support curl, this script does not work.
if(isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) && $recaptcha_secret_key !== '') {
    $endpoint = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret_key . '&response=' . $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ;
    $curl = curl_init() ;
    curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_URL , $endpoint ) ;
    curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false ) ;
    curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true ) ;
    curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 5 ) ;
    $json = curl_exec( $curl ) ;
    curl_close( $curl ) ;

    if($json == FALSE) {
        returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
            constructAjaxResponseArray(
                FALSE,
                'RECAPTCHA_FAILED',
                array('error_message'=> 'RECAPTCHA_FAILED')
            )
        );
    }

    $json = json_decode($json);

    if($json->success === FALSE) {
        returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
            constructAjaxResponseArray(
                FALSE,
                'RECAPTCHA_FAIL_RESPONSE',
                array('error_message'=> 'Recaptcha response is not valid.')
            )
        );
    }
}

// Check $recipient
if($recipient === '') {
    returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
        constructAjaxResponseArray(
            FALSE,
            'RECIPIENT_IS_NOT_SET',
            array('error_message'=> 'RECIPIENT email address is not set. Please configure the script.')
        )
    );
}

// Check for empty required field
if(!isset($_POST["email"]) || !isset($_POST["fname"]) || !isset($_POST["message"])) {
    returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
        constructAjaxResponseArray(
            FALSE,
            'MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELDS',
            array('error_message'=> 'MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELDS should not be occurred.')
        )
    );
}

// Sanitize input
$fname  = filter_var($_POST["fname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$lname  = filter_var($_POST["lname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$message = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);

// If non required fields are empty
if ( empty($lname) ){
    $lname = "No last name entered.";
}
if ( empty($website) ){
    $website = "No website entered.";
}

// Headers
$headers = 'From: '.$fname.' <'.$email.'>' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Subject
$subject = "New booking from contact form";

// Build Message
$email_content = "First Name: $fname\n";
$email_content .= "Last Name: $lname\n";
$email_content .= "Phone: $phone\n";
 $email_content .= "Date: $date\n"; 
$email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
$email_content .= "Location: $location\n";
$email_content .= "Preferred Contact Time: $contacttime\n";
$email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n\n\n";
$email_content .= "CLIENT IP:\n".get_client_ip()."\n";
$email_content .= "HOST IP:\n".$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']."\n";

// Check if sent 
try {
$sendmailResult = mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $headers);
if( $sendmailResult === TRUE ) {
    returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
        constructAjaxResponseArray(
            TRUE
        )
    );
} else {
    returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
        constructAjaxResponseArray(
            FALSE,
            'ERROR_AT_PHPMAIL',
            array('error_information'=> error_get_last() )
        )
    );
}
} catch (Exception $_e) {
returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
    constructAjaxResponseArray(
        TRUE,
        'ERROR_AT_PHPMAIL',
        array('error_message'=> $_e->getMessage())
    )
);
}

/*
Construct ajax response array
Input: Result (bool), Message (optional), Data to be sent back in array
*/
function constructAjaxResponseArray ($_response, $_message = '', $_json = 
null) {
$_responseArray = array();
$_response = ( $_response === TRUE ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
$_responseArray['response'] = $_response;
if(isset($_message)) $_responseArray['message'] = $_message;
if(isset($_json)) $_responseArray['json'] = $_json;

return $_responseArray;
}
/*
Returns in the Gframe ajax format.
Input: data array processed by constructAjaxResponseArray ()
Outputs as a html stream then exits.
*/
function returnAndExitAjaxResponse ($_ajaxResponse) {
if(!$_ajaxResponse){
    $_ajaxResponse = array('response'=>false,'message'=>'Unknown error 
occurred.');
}
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($_ajaxResponse);
die();
}


// Function to get the client IP address
function get_client_ip() {
$ipaddress = '';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])) {
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
} else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])) {
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
} else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
} else {
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
}
return $ipaddress;
}
```

Here is my form section:

```
<!-- Contact Form -->
            <section class="section-block replicable-content contact-2">
                <div class="row">


                    <div class="column width-8">
                        <div class="contact-form-container">
                            <form class="contact-form" action="php/send 
email.php" method="post" novalidate>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="column width-6">
                                        <div class="field-wrapper">
                                            <input type="text" name="fname" 
class="form-fname form-element large" placeholder="First Name*" tabindex="1" 
required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column width-6">
                                        <div class="field-wrapper">
                                            <input type="text" name="lname" 
class="form-lname form-element large" placeholder="Last Name*" tabindex="2" 
required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column width-6">
                                        <div class="field-wrapper">
                                            <input type="email" name="email" 
class="form-email form-element large" placeholder="Email address*" 
tabindex="3" 
required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column width-6">
                                        <div class="field-wrapper">
                                            <input type="tel" name="phone" 
class="form-element large" placeholder="Phone*" tabindex="4">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column width-6">
                                        <div class="field-wrapper">
                                            <input type="text" name="date" 
class="form-element large" placeholder="Test (SAT ACT GRE) & Test Date*" 
 tabindex="5">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column width-6">
                                        <div class="field-wrapper">
                                        <input type="text" name="location" 
class=" form-element large" placeholder="City & State*" tabindex="6" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="column width-6">
                                         <div class="field-wrapper">
                                        <input type="text" 
 name="contacttime" class=" form-element large" placeholder="Preferred 
Contact Date & Time*" tabindex="7" >
                                         </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="column width-6">
                                        <input type="text" name="honeypot" 
class="form-honeypot form-element">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="column width-12">
                                        <div class="field-wrapper">
                                            <textarea name="message" 
class="form-message form-element large" placeholder="Message*" tabindex="7" 
required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column width-12">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Send 
Email" class="form-submit button medium bkg-greem color-white color-hover- 
white" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div class="form-response"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



            </section>
            <!--Contact Form End -->
```

I apologize if this is poor formatting, this is my first post.

Comment: Where are you actually setting the variables used for those items? `$location`, `$contacttime`, etc

Comment: Do I have to declare these? I'm not well experienced with php, but I didn't think anything additional needed to be added since the email, first, last name, and message weren't declared anywhere that I could see.

Comment: Just like any other variable, if you don't _give_ these values, they won't _have_ values.  If you don't know about assigning values to variables, I highly suggest that you stop and go through some introductory lessons/classes/tutorials and the PHP manual before you make a costly mistake.